# Milne's Intersection theory simple example

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, intersection-theory

In Milne's [Divisors and intersection theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG12.pdf), Example 12.3a) computes the intersection number of the curves $Z_1: Y=X^2$ and $Z_2: Y^2=X^3$ at the intersection point $P=(0,0)$ in the affine plane over a base field $k$.

By definition

$(Z_1 \cdot Z_2)_P = $ $\dim_k O_P/(Y-X^2, Y^2-X^3) = 
\dim_k k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(Y-X^2, Y-X^3) $

The author states that this dimension is equal to $\dim_k k[X]/(X^4-X^3)$ (so, equal to 3). Why is that true?

I would say at most that

$k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(Y-X^2, Y-X^3) = k[X]_{(X)}/(X^4-X^3) $

but this has dimension greater than 3, since contains for example powers like $1/(X-1)$ which are linearly independent from $1, X, X^2$.

Comment: What is going on here is that $V(Y - X^2)$ is isomorphic to $A^1 = Spec k[X]$, and when you pullback $Y^2 - X^3$ you get $X^4 - X^3$. When you localize at $(X)$, since localization commutes with taking a quotient, you get $k[x] / x^3$, which has dimension 3. (I think there is a typo in Milne, because $k[x]/(X^3(X - 1)) \cong k[x]/x^3 \times k[x]/(x -1)$ has dimension 4 as a $k$-vector space. However note that when you localize $(x -1) = (1)$ (as ideals), so the right hand term in the product disappears.)

Comment: Somewhat concretely: the old formula $1/(1-X) = 1 + X + X^2 + \cdots$ is suggestive here. I agree that Milne has a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reason as follows:

the element $X-1$ is invertible $k[X]_{(X)}$, so the generator $X^4-X^3=X^3(X-1)$ is equal to $X^3$ up to unit.

Conclude that $k[X]_{(X)}/(X^4−X^3)=k[X]_{(X)}/(X^3)=(k[X]/(X^3))_{(X)k[X]/(X^3)}=k[X]/(X^3)$, the last equality being true since $k[X]/(X^3)$ is already a local ring.